# Passing a column name through a function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to pass a column name through the `bi_class` function within my broader `create_sf_func()` function to use to create tertile cutoffs for bivariate maps in R. I am using the following code, but cannot figure out how to get R to recognize my `variable` argument of my function as a variable in the dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#LIBRARIES
library(tidyverse)
library(biscale)
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(stringr)

#Get Sample of FIPS codes
all_fips <- get(data(fips_codes)) %>%
  mutate(FIPS5 = paste0(state_code, county_code)) %>%
  select(FIPS5) %>%
  head(100)
  
#Create example data
df <- data.frame(all_fips[1], YrQrt = sample(c("2022Q1", "2022Q2"), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)),
                 TestRate=runif(100, 0, 60), 
                 CaseRate=runif(100, 0, 70), 
                 DeathRate=runif(100, 0, 30)) %>%
  mutate(FIPS5 = str_pad(FIPS5, width=5, pad="0"))


#Produce tertiles for x and y variables and produce geometry shapes for the FIPS codes
df_cases <- bi_class(df, x = TestRate, y = CaseRate, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
df_cases2022Q2 <- sf::st_as_sf(df_cases %>% filter(YrQrt == "2022Q2") %>% 
                                 mutate(geometry = fips_geometry(FIPS5)) %>% filter(FIPS5<60), crs = 4269) %>% 
  shift_geometry()
```

This is where I am trying to turn the above into a function because I have a number of variables to perform this on:

```
#Turn the above tertile and geometry production into a function
create_sf_func <- function(yrqrt, variable) {
  
  df2 <- bi_class(df, x = TestRate, y = ensym(variable), style = "quantile", dim = 3)
  
  df_filtered <- sf::st_as_sf(df2 %>% filter(YrQrt== yrqrt) %>% 
                                right_join(all_fips, by=c("FIPS5"="FIPS5")) %>% 
                                mutate(geometry = fips_geometry(FIPS5)) %>% filter(FIPS5<60), crs = 4269) %>% 
    shift_geometry()
  return(df_filtered)
}

#run function
df_cases2022Q2 <- create_sf_func("2022Q2", "CaseRate")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had a look at your previous question and the only option which worked for me was to use `do.call` to call `bi_class` and pass the variable name:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(biscale)
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(fipio)

set.seed(123)

create_sf_func <- function(yrqrt, variable) {
  df2 <- do.call(bi_class, list(df, x = "TestRate", y = variable, style = "quantile", dim = 3))

  df_filtered <- sf::st_as_sf(df2 %>% filter(YrQrt == yrqrt) %>%
    right_join(all_fips, by = c("FIPS5" = "FIPS5")) %>%
    mutate(geometry = fips_geometry(FIPS5)) %>% filter(FIPS5 < 60), crs = 4269) %>%
    shift_geometry()

  return(df_filtered)
}

df_cases2022Q2 <- create_sf_func("2022Q2", "CaseRate")
#> Warning: st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for
#> that

df_cases2022Q2
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 6 fields (with 5 geometries empty)
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -3115585 ymin: -1702302 xmax: 1044909 ymax: -230281.9
#> Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
#> First 10 features:
#>    FIPS5  YrQrt  TestRate  CaseRate DeathRate bi_class
#> 1  01001 2022Q2 35.999338 16.710822 23.537258      2-1
#> 2  01005 2022Q2 29.316782 42.095601 23.371976      2-2
#> 3  01011 2022Q2 53.421013 61.617258 14.427325      3-3
#> 4  01019 2022Q2  8.825681 12.052022 14.768800      1-1
#> 5  01023 2022Q2 18.073734 17.707545 13.939978      1-1
#> 6  01029 2022Q2 43.235776  3.336454 10.643493      3-1
#> 7  01033 2022Q2 32.957079 24.632205 25.071265      2-2
#> 8  01035 2022Q2 57.245474 28.626080  7.132482      3-2
#> 9  01037 2022Q2 35.129001 57.466593 10.619583      2-3
#> 10 01057 2022Q2  8.514414 48.878312 10.151739      1-3
#>                          geometry
#> 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((858778.6 -5...
#> 2  MULTIPOLYGON (((997958.5 -6...
#> 3  MULTIPOLYGON (((972148.2 -5...
#> 4  MULTIPOLYGON (((953138.5 -2...
#> 5  MULTIPOLYGON (((745962.9 -6...
#> 6  MULTIPOLYGON (((953876.1 -3...
#> 7  MULTIPOLYGON (((777011.4 -2...
#> 8  MULTIPOLYGON (((881959.9 -6...
#> 9  MULTIPOLYGON (((929183.3 -4...
#> 10 MULTIPOLYGON (((766776.4 -3...
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Any insight as to why it doesn't work without do.call()?

Comment: Hm. IMHO this looks like a bug, i.e. from the error one gets it's clear that under the hood `bi_class` is looking for a column called `variable` instead of for the column whose name is stored  in `variable`, whether you pass the column name as a string or whether using `ensym()`.